# Using quiver3 when performing photometric stereo 3D function

Tags: matlab, vector, plot, direction

I have 5 images with 5 different light sources. Based on this I have created a matrix with the normals of each pixel, which is an N X 3 matrix. I need to use quiver3 to show the surface normals. I have no idea how to fill in quiver3. Can I use the normals? What do I link x, y, z with? The image? And since the image is x, y, how do I know z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have not recovered shape yet, your depth value `z` is zero everywhere. Once you recover shape you will have non-trivial values for `z`.

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039874/user4039874), `nor` is a 512-by-512-by-3 array and I assume the image has the same size as well. Then

```
sz = size(nor(:,:,1));
[y x] = ndgrid( 1:sz(1), 1:sz(2) );  %// values for x and y should be of size [512 512]
z = zeros( size(x) );
figure;
imshow( img ); hold on;
quiver3( x, y, z, nor(:,:,1), nor(:,:,2), nor(:,:,3) );
```

Most likely the resulting vector field will be too dense. you might want to consider displaying a normal vector every 5 pixels or so.

Comment: I did compute a 2D height array, which I inserted as you suggested. I get complaints that Z and U are not the same dimension.

Comment: @user4039874 what are the sizes of your `x`, `y`, `z` and `nor`?

Comment: Using size(): x = [1 1], y = [1 1], z = [512 512], normal = [512 512 3]

Comment: clearly you `x` and `y` are wrong. please see my edit.

Comment: You were right. I found out why my dimensions were all wrong. Thank you for your help!